# Using local OSM server in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, osm2pgsql

I have a local OSM server that cached osm.pbf.

How can I add data from this server to ArcMap like a base map layer?

OSM was made by instr: https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the OSM format is not natively supported by ArcGIS. You may want to take a look at [ArcBrutile](https://github.com/ArcBruTile/ArcBruTile/) which supposedly does have suport for OSM. I haven't tried this myself though.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [ArcQMS](https://my.nextgis.com/downloads/software/arcqms/ArcQMSInstaller.msi) plugin. This plugin allows to add basemaps from [qms.nextgis.com](https://qms.nextgis.com/) - the service with lot of basemaps.

Unfortunately private resources is not available now in QMS, so you need to publish your OSM server as public. If your server behind the NAT and not seen from Internet this is not a problem for you I think.